# Mount .vdi Image from Read-Only-Device

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and would like to mount a .vdi Image as device from a read-only drive.

I've been trying qemu:

```
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /media/mount/VirtualBox\ VMs/Lu\ Buntu/Lu\ Buntu.vdi 
Failed to blk_new_open '/media/mount/VirtualBox VMs/Lu Buntu/Lu Buntu.vdi': 
Could not open '/media/mount/VirtualBox VMs/Lu Buntu/Lu Buntu.vdi': Read-only file system
```

I don't want to move and convert the vdi to my local file System as it's quite big. Opening it via VirtualBox is also not possible as the file system on which it's located on is read-only and it fails for similar reasons.

Seems there is that package from eight years ago: virtualbox-fuse, but before I'm installing that I'd like to know if there are alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you tried `--read-only` option of `qemu-nbd` command (see [`man qemu-nbd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/qemu-nbd.8.html))?

Comment: @N0rbert - can you provide an example-command? Googling it refers to my own question and it seems it's mostly if you want to mount it read-only. Extending my command gives me an `invalid number of arguments`, so I assume I place it wrongly